# why my cypher query return null?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two structure with different label:

tree node's label:Person

graph nodes'label:Friend

1)tree:

```
a-->b-->d
|   |
|    -->e
|
 -->c-->f
    |
     -->g
    |
     -->h
```

2)graph:

```
b-->a-->f-->g-->b
    |
     -->b
```

I have this cypher query and what i expect return is : "b"

but it return null. how I must write this query????

```
MATCH (a),(b)
WHERE a.name='ali'
AND (a:Friend)-[:FRIEND_OF]-(b:Friend)
AND (a:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b:Person)
RETURN b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you could explain what you're trying to do. I don't really understand.

Since the relationship between people already has tags (`FRIEND_OF`, `PARENT_OF`), why would you use a `Friend` node label? Unless you have a good reason, I would just have nodes with a `Person` tag.

The query you posted will return person nodes who are friends with ali and where Ali is his/her parent. It can be rewritten to:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name:"ali"})-[:FRIEND_OF]-(b:Person)
WHERE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
RETURN b.name
```

I don't have your data set so it's hard to test for the results. You are stating that you are not getting any results.

Can you verify that:

- There is only one node with name ali and it has the 2 relationships you are looking for? If there are 2 nodes with name ali and each of them has one of the afore mentioned relationships Neo4j won't find any matches. You are looking for exactly one node which has both relationships.
- Node b exists and has a name property?

Comment: hello. i have this two struture with different label. 

http://www.4shared.com/photo/BZaGC0K9ce/Screenshot_from_2014-07-12_09_.html

 and
http://www.4shared.com/photo/EAUP1p3Zce/Screenshot_from_2014-07-12_09_.html

 I want to get nodes that in "Person" are children of 'hassan' node ,and in "Friend" , 'hassan' is them's friend

Comment: Can you please try to provide more details? Are you looking for a person who is Hasan's child and at the same time his friend? I don't really see the difference between that and the query I've posted above except for the name, which is Ali instead of Hassan...